# Error creating Files in remote server from a ASP .NET 4.0 Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

NET web service to upload files from an infopath form to a Windows Server but it fails. I am Catchin the exception so I don't have the Accurate error:

```
private bool ExistDirectory(string p_Directory)
{
    try
    {
        return Directory.Exists(p_Directory);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private bool CreateDirectory(string p_Directory)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(p_Directory);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have the credentials for the remote server but I don't know how to use it.  Any Idea?

Comment: If you are catching the exception, do output it somewhere where you can actually check it. This is the first step to know what is going on.

Comment: **Access to the path 'Path' is denied**....    I Published it in another server and it works.... the unique diference is that is not working on FW 4.0 and is working in FW 3.5....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved it with this link:

[http://forums.asp.net/t/2020054.aspx?C+Web+service+System+UnauthorizedAccessException+Access+to+the+path+is+denied+](http://forums.asp.net/t/2020054.aspx?C%20Web%20service%20System%20UnauthorizedAccessException%20Access%20to%20the%20path%20is%20denied%20)

Basicly I added "NetWork Service" account to folder permissions and appPool identity Permisions...